# Get font awesome icon by class

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using font awesome icons on my website as such

```
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
```

and I want to style them from an external style sheet.  I tried using

```
.fa {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

and

```
.fa-plus {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

but neither of those had any effect.  If I use inline

```
<i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size: 64px;"></i>
```

or if I use an ID attribute

```
<i class="fa fa-plus" id="plus"></i>
```

and style it with

```
#plus {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

that works fine, but I would like to avoid adding unnecessary ID attributes or using inline CSS.  I can also change the color of the icon by using

```
.fa {
  color: red;
}
```

And that works perfectly fine no matter where I put it.  I changed my CSS link to after the font awesome import and that made no difference.

Edit:

I had a selector further up that styled the `<i>` tag

Comment: It is better not directly select the font-awesome icon. But select parent of the icon and apply style via `.parent .child`

Comment: Where do you include your own stylesheet, and where font-awesome.

Comment: If an ID works, that means that there is a rule with higher precedence that is 'stealing' the font size. Find out what it is with your inspector. Perhaps `i.fa` already works.

Comment: @baao Webapge may have lot of font-awesome icons with same class. If it was not meant to style in same way, applying style directly to class may affect all

Comment: I thought that's what he is wanting @melvin

Comment: @bram the id would override the class' style https://jsfiddle.net/ve4zn53h/1/

Comment: @baao Not sure what you mean. What I am saying is: if he tried giving an ID, and that works, then that means that it is a precedence issue because the ID overrides some class. If that is the case, OP can use a more specific selector (but not necessarily an ID) to solve their issue.

Comment: @Ben, what about `fa fa-plus-2x` ?

Comment: Weird your first snippet should work, only if your css comes after the font awesome link

Comment: @BramVanroy I'm saying it's a precedence issue. My bet is they include their style before fa. The id selector would still work, but a class would be overriden by the fa stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the `:not()` selector that will allow you to add a random ID and to have a more specific selector. This work because the specificity of `not()` is equal to the specificty of the selector inside:

```css
.fa-plus:not(#randomId) {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" >
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using !important, it is not best practice but sometimes its best option. eg.

property:value !important;